# How to display the applications using RAM memory more than 200mb in a list?

Tags: android, performance, android-permissions, android-memory

i want the display all the applications using the RAM memory more than 200mb( for example in my mobile there are 200 applications out those 40 applications are using the RAM memory more than 200mb then i need to display those applications in a list)

Thanks In Advance....and help or suggestion are welcome......

Comment: [Quoting Dianne Hackborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813) (one of the Android core engineers): "Note that memory usage on modern operating systems like Linux is an extremely complicated and difficult to understand area. In fact the chances of you actually correctly interpreting whatever numbers you get is extremely low." You need to explain **precisely** what you think "using the RAM memory" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare "useing the RAM memory" means in android 6.0 memory is provided in settings so that let us say Instagram is consuming 245mb then i want to display that app in the list with used memory......Hope im clear this time....

Comment: "in android 6.0 memory is provided in settings" -- then you are going to have to look through the source code to the Settings app and find out what it happens to use for its memory calculations.